# Adding a new language to the Odoo ERP

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to add a new language to the Odoo openERP (installed on the local machine) which is not on the list of its languages.
I changed the string in some `.po` files but it did not affect the translated view in the app.
Any idea to change language easily by editing the `.po` file for other languages? for example changing the string of the `fr.po` to the desired one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps, I followed to add a new language (Sindhi) in odoo. After creating a language file (.po) follow these steps, make sure to replace language with whatever you want to add:

Step 1 - Activate developer mode.

Step 2 - From Settings --> Translations --> Import / Export, import translation file (.po) with Sindhi / سنڌي as Language Name, sn_PK as code

Step 3 - After importing, you should see the Sindhi / سنڌي in settings --> Translations --> Languages.

Step 4 - Now you can set your language from the user preference menu.